# Automator action to paste a word in all fonts

Tags: applescript, automator, pages, font

How would I write an Automator action or Applescript to paste or type a word in every single font?  The screenshot is what I have so far.  The hitch I'm running into is in the "make a selection from the popupbutton" stage.  Because Pages keeps a list of the last 6 fonts you used, you can't just click on the font drop-down and press "down".  You'd have to do it at least 6 times, then "n+1" every single time afterward, and Automator doesn't let me edit the results of recording UI actions.[image: automator]
[image: fonts]

Comment: You'd need something a bit more programmatic than scripting 'movement', I think. You could use the AppleScript ObjC bridge to query the OS's Font Manager, and then create rich text objects for each one. But it would be 'non-trivial'. Can I ask why you want this? There are font manager/viewing apps that will produce text in every available font, for instance.

Comment: i need to see how all these fonts write in greek.  looking through fontbook, i don't see any way to view that.  can you assist?  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can realize your goal without writing any code line - the Font Book allows you this,
just proceed as follows:

- In your Font Book, click on the `+` sign in the lower left corner, and add a new
  font collection - and from `All Fonts` list, just drag a specific font and drop
  it to the new collection. See the picture below. (This makes only a list, not install
  anything new.)

[image]

- Now select your new collection, select all fonts in the list, or just only some items,
  and in the right pane just tap on a row of any font; that will show the editing cursor,
  and you can write a word or a short sentence.
- Press the sign `A|` in the toolbar to `Switch to custom preview mode`
  to transfer your word/sentence to all selected fonts.

Note that closing the Font Book will save your collection and the word/sentence typed in.

Comment: Apple provides a [detailed description on the options you have in Fontbook](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/font-book/fntbk1001/mac) to do this.

Comment: YOU DA REAL MVP